# What is the right way and efficiently query the array list data from MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Very new to this! Let says I have this document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("00000000000000000"),
"keyArray" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Miche",
        "score" : 0,
        "gender": "M",
        "group" : "A"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "kim",
        "score" : -1,
        "gender": "F",
        "group" : "B"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "john",
        "score" : 1,
        "gender": "M",
        "group" : "A"
    }
],
"key" : "value",
"key" : "value",
...
}
```

How can I just list all the data from `keyArray` instead of showing other keys?

`db.users.find({}, { _id: 0, keyArray: { $elemMatch: {group: "A" }}})` (this will only shows the first item)

I would like to query all list data from `keyArray` without `$elemMatch`

```
{
    "name" : "Miche",
    "score" : 0,
    "gender": "M",
    "group" : "A"
}, 
{
    "name" : "kim",
    "score" : -1,
    "gender": "F",
    "group" : "A"
}, 
{
    "name" : "john",
    "score" : 1,
    "gender": "M",
    "group" : "A"
}
```

then what's the right way to query and delete items from the array where score < 0?

```
.findOneAndDelete( where { users.keyArray.score: { "score" : -1 }} )

.update( { }, { $pull: { keyArray.score: -1 } }, { multi: true } )
```

Need a bit of help to show the way out.

Comment: db.users.find({}, {keyArray:true}) will return only the keyArray data

Comment: @theTradeCoder Could you tell me more about delete the item by score?

Comment: here you can find a solution for this case to delete based on score [Remove Items from an Array of Documents- mongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/),

Comment: @theTradeCoder: post this as an answer that the OP can accept..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get only some specified fields from mongoDB

```
db.users.find({}, {keyArray:true})
```

This will return only keyArray data. You can add more fields if you need, by this way,

```
db.users.find({}, {field1:true, field2:true, field3:true})
```

Also works with `findOne({})` where necessary.

And for deleting/updating some specified fields/ documents in an Array, for your case, this official document will help you to understand details [Remove Items from an Array of Documents- mongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)